# Como printar algo dentro da janela em Python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def text():
    print('Olá, mundo!')


from tkinter import *
janela = Tk()
janela.title('Teste')
janela.geometry('800x800')
botao = Button(janela,text='Clique aqui',command=text)
botao.grid(column=0,row=0)
janela.mainloop()´´´


Ao clicar no botão, o texto só é printado dentro do IDE, queria que fosse possível printá-lo para a janela do programa, de modo a ficar visível para qualquer usuário, sem precisar necessariamente ver o código.
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para criar um label com texto modificável você irá precisar de um label e uma stringvar, abaixo segue um exemplo:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
label_var = StringVar()
label = Label(master, textvariable=label_var).pack()

def msg():
    label_var.set('Olá Mundo')

button = Button(master, text="Mostrar Mensagem", command=msg)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Quando você usa o 'print' o resultado é exibido apenas no console/prompt

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Porém, gostaria de saber o que exatamente faz a função "pack(_)"?

Comment: O pack é o gerenciador de layout do tkinter, ele coloca como visível seu widget, outras opções são o place() e o grid(), cada um funciona de uma forma